# Why some of most popular AMI are not available on all regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'm new to AWS, we are using [this RHEL AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B019NS7T5I?qid=1491916444943&sr=0-4&ref_=srh_res_product_title) for our test environment, initially we wanted to use Canada region, but later figured out that our AIM is not available there for some reason, I wonder why? RHEL AMIs from amazon web services are not available in Canada not 7.x, nor 6.x versions, I guess technically it's not really a problem, so AWS is doing this because of policies of some sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An AMI is a regional resource in AWS, because it's tied to the region where its files are located within Amazon S3. However, if in need, you can copy an AMI from one region to another:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html

And more info about resource locations in AWS :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/resources.html